# How to use aggregate functions on each array in a table, in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Imagine I have a table like:

```
games (
    scores INTEGER[]
)
```

And it had values

```
{1,2}
{3,4}
{}
```

I'd like to do arbitrary aggregations on that array.

For example, how would I do `SELECT SUM(scores) AS total FROM games`? Or an average? Or a max?

I'd like to get out:

```
3
7 
0
```

I tried `SELECT SUM(UNNEST(scores)) AS total FROM games` but that gave `ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot contain set-returning function calls`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a scalar subquery:

```
select (select sum(i)
        from unnest(scores) as x(i)) as total
from games;
```